# How to parse a dynamic Json - Power Automate

Tags: json, object, parsing, power-automate

Im getting a http response from Azure LogAnalytics, the response is a Json like this

```
{
 "tables": [
{
  "name": "PrimaryResult",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "TimeGenerated",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "DestinationIP",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "DestinationUserName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "country_name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "country_iso_code",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "AccountCustomEntity",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "2021-05-17T14:07:01.878Z",
      "158.000.000.33",
      "luis",
      "United States",
      "US",
      "luis"
       ]
     ] 
   } 
 ]
}
```

I will never get the same colums or sometimes i will get more rows with data like this

```
  {
 "tables": [
{
  "name": "PrimaryResult",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Account",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "Computer",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "IpAddress",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "AccountType",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "Activity",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "LogonTypeName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "ProcessName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "StartTimeUtc",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "EndTimeUtc",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "ConnectinCount",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "AccountCustomEntity",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "HostCustomEntity",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "IPCustomEntity",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "abc\\abc",
      "EQ-DC02.abc.LOCAL",
      "0.0.0.0",
      "User",
      "4624 - An account was successfully logged on.",
      "10 - RemoteInteractive",
      "C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe",
      "2021-05-17T15:02:25.457Z",
      "2021-05-17T15:02:25.457Z",
      2,
      "2021-05-17T15:02:25.457Z",
      "abc\\abc",
      "EQ-DC02.abc.LOCAL",
      "0.0.0.0"
    ],
    [
      "abc\\eona",
      "EQPD-SW01.abc.LOCAL",
      "0.0.0.0",
      "User",
      "4624 - An account was successfully logged on.",
      "10 - RemoteInteractive",
      "C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe",
      "2021-05-17T15:21:45.993Z",
      "2021-05-17T15:21:45.993Z",
      1,
      "2021-05-17T15:21:45.993Z",
      "abc\\abc",
      "EQPD-SW01.abc.LOCAL",
      "0.0.0.0"
    ]
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Im using Power Automate to parse this kind of Json to a Object or to make a response
the question is, how can i parse this "Columns" and "Rows" to a object?

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

[Similar discussion](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Parse-dynamic-JSON-for-every-array-element-and-every-key-value/td-p/385080) happened in community forum and the [solution identified](http://johnliu.net/blog/2017/11/foreach-property-in-microsoftflow-json-with-xpath-microblog) was:

> parse JSON and transform it to XML and then search keys with XPATH in Flow